# txt file extract only 8 digit numbersand transform to date format

Tags: php

I have a txt file that contains text and code.

```
<div data-role='day' data-day='20131225'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>kerst</h1>sdfg' data-start='Van 00:00u ' data-end='00:00u' data-location='thuis'></div></div>
<div data-role='day' data-day='20131212'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>SDV</h1>GGG' data-start='Van begin ' data-end='einde' data-location='FGF'></div></div>
```

Is it possible to extract all 8 digit numbers for this txt file 20131225 and 20131212, and transform them in the format 2013/12/25 .... and not only for these dates...also for future dates that will be added if an event is added to the txt file...so i dont know which dates this will be...and also display that in correct date format and echo only these dates out. I was thinking about preg replace but i dont succeed.... can soeone help me. thx

Comment: affirmative red leader.

Comment: solved thx everybody for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming this file is actually have this format for all strings, you can go with regexp, this will be faster neither xml/html parsing

next thing - I do not recommend using of strtotime, as soon as format is clear you can go with faster variant:

```
<?php

$s = "<div data-role='day' data-day='20131225'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>kerst</h1>sdfg' data-start='Van 00:00u ' data-end='00:00u' data-location='thuis'></div></div>
<div data-role='day' data-day='20131212'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>SDV</h1>GGG' data-start='Van begin ' data-end='einde' data-location='FGF'></div></div>";

preg_match_all('/data-day=\'([^\']*)\'/', $s, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $idx => $datevalue)
{
    $year = substr($datevalue, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($datevalue, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($datevalue, 6, 2);
    echo $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The data you have can be called a `text file that contains data and code` :), of course, but usually one would call that a  "`HTML`" document.

For parsing `HTML` with PHP there is the [dom extension](http://www.php.net/book.dom). Use it like this:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div data-role='day' data-day='20131225'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>kerst</h1>sdfg' data-start='Van 00:00u ' data-end='00:00u' data-location='thuis'></div></div>
<div data-role='day' data-day='20131212'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>SDV</h1>GGG' data-start='Van begin ' data-end='einde' data-location='FGF'></div></div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// create an XPath selector to select the attributes containing the dates
$selector = new DOMXpath($doc);

// select all data-day attributes
foreach($selector->query('//@data-day') as $date) {
    // transform date format using date() and strotime()
    echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date->nodeValue));
}
```

For the date conversion I've used [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). You should read their manuals as well.

Comment: thx alot that helps :) finally i am searching all day for something like this :)